# How to stop ec2 with crontab at @reboot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I am using crontab on a Linux ec2 to run some code when the instance starts.
The first two lines of the crontab run correctly, but I cannot make the instance stop after 120 seconds.

```
@reboot python3 run.py
@reboot python3 run2.py
@reboot sleep 120 aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-059............
```

If I run the was command in the terminal works without issues, is only in crontab that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complete command:

```
sleep 120
```

This is another complete command:

```
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-059
```

You can't just smash multiple commands together like you are attempting. If you tried running `sleep 120 aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-059` you would see an error message. That error message is also probably showing up in your server's cron log.

The solution is to place a semicolon delimiter between the commands, like so:

```
sleep 120 ; aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-059
```

This tells the Linux shell to run the first command and wait for it to finish, then run the second command.

Comment: thank you, for whoever is reading I used && and worked